# Batch file selection based on partial filename, or highest number

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to come up with a small menu structure and resulting file selection to apply Windows image files.

Scenario:
I want to be able to select a single WIM file from a directory with an option to either choose the newest, or a specific version, based on the numbering.

`Image_Name_101.wim
 Image_Name_102.wim
 Image_Name_103.wim`

etc. exist, user can either go for option (1) and pick the highest number/latest image, or manually enter the revision number to choose an older image.

Ideally, the selected file is then passed into a DISM command, which applies the image. (eg `dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:X:\*Image_Name_102.wim* /Index:1 /ApplyDir:C:\` )

I have found somewhat similar examples but fail to apply them to my project.
Any pointers, hints, help is welcome.

Comment: This is not a question but a code/script request, which is off-topic here! Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for %%a in (imagename*.wim) do (
  set /a count+=1
  echo !count!  %%a
  set "file[!count!]=%%a"
)
:Loop
set /p "nr=Enter Number: "
set /a nr=%nr%
if %nr% leq 0 goto :Loop
if %nr% gtr %count% goto :Loop

ECHO dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:X:\!file[%nr%]! /Index:1 /ApplyDir:C:\
```

remove the `ECHO` when the output is ok.

the `for` loop enumerates all matching files. The `:Loop` part gets user input and does a basic input validation.